# Viper is not considering the yaml tags in my structs on unmarshalling

Tags: go, yaml, viper-go

when I use the `Unmarshal` method of viper to fill my config structs with the values in my yaml file, some of the struct fields became empty!
I do it in this way:

```
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
viper.SetConfigName("config")
viper.AddConfigPath("/etc/myapp/")
viper.AddConfigPath(".")

err := viper.ReadInConfig()
// error checking ...
conf := &ConfYaml{}
err = viper.Unmarshal(conf)
// error checking ...
```

And my structs are like this:

```
type ConfYaml struct {
    Endpoints SectionStorageEndpoint `yaml:"endpoints"`
}

type SectionStorageEndpoint struct {
    URL       string `yaml:"url"`
    AccessKey string `yaml:"access_key"`
    SecretKey string `yaml:"secret_key"`
    UseSSL    bool   `yaml:"use_ssl"`
    Location  string `yaml:"location"`
}
```

Here the `url` and `location` fields are filled with proper value in the yaml file, but the other fields are empty!

It's wondering that when I try to print a field like:

```
viper.Get("endpoints.access_key")
```

it prints the proper value in the yaml file and **is not empty**!!

Comment: Can you please include a _complete_ verifiable example, complete with the actual output and what you expected instead?

Comment: @Flimzy yeah, I updated the question, hope it be enough.

Comment: So you expect it to be empty?

Comment: @Flimzy No, I expect all the fields to be filled with the value in the yaml file. But some values like url and location are filled and others are empty! when I print the empty ones with the viper.Get() they are not empty! so the unmarshalling method is not working properly for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found the solution, changing `yaml:` tags to `mapstructure:` will fix the problem.

It seems that viper couldn't unmarshal the fields that haven't the same key name in my `.yaml` file. Like the `access_key` and `secret_key` in the question, cause the struct fields where `AccessKey` and `SecretKey`.

But the fields like `location` and `url` that had the same name in the struct and `.yaml` file, and there was no problem.

As [this issue](https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/385) says:

> The problem is that `viper` uses mapstructure package for
>   unmarshalling config maps to structs. It doesn't support yaml tags
>   used by the yaml package.

So changing the `yaml:` in the tags to `mapstructure:` had fixed the problem.

Comment: viper first unmarshal all fields into an empty interface then use the [mapstructure](https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package to unmarshal it into a specific structure.

Comment: so the problem is with mapstructure that can’t understand `yaml:` tags?

Comment: mapstructure converts the given string to empty interface map into a struct so it must not understand the yaml tags :)